# How can a sequence be downloaded from UCSC genome browser

Tags: genomics

If I have genome coordinates is there a simple way to download the entire intervening sequence from the UCSC genome browser? I found some fancy way of using ftp but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [Table browser](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTables?hgsid=445103435_wVaUoR2DgtHy4q52jL0PavpZn853) allows you to do that.

In the dropdown box called `output format` select `sequence` and click the button named `get output`. You'll get the sequence.

If you don't think it works then this is the output that I am getting. (Fist few lines):

```
>hg19_gold_AL096773.6 range=chr1:115207623-115347729 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=- repeatMasking=none
GATCTGCCAGCGTCCACCTCCCGAGGTGCCGGGATTGCAGACGGAGTCTG
GTTCACTCAGTGCTCAATGGTGCCCAGGCTGGAGTGCAGTGGCGTGATCT
CGGCTCGCTACAACCTCCACCTCCCAGCCGCCTGCCCTGGCCTCCCAAAG
TGCCGAGATTGCAGCCTCTGCCCAGCCGCCACCCCGTCTGGGAAGTGAGG
AGCATCTCTGCCTGGCCGCCCATCATCTGGGATGTGAGGAGCCCCTCTGC
CTGGCTGCCCAGTCTGGGAAGTGAGGAGCGCCTCTTCCCGGCCGCCATCC
```

Actually Table browser is quite useful as you can get different kinds of data for a given genomic region which include annotations, variation, transcription factor binding sites etc.

Comment: Actually this does not seem to give me intervening sequence for coordinates. (I'm trying this: chr1:115227814-115227978) It just outputs some coordinates.

Comment: @TheNightman In the dropdown box called `output format` select `sequence` and click the button named `get output`. You'll get the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I did find a way of doing this using UCSC das. If the pertinent info is changed in the page address here, it will output the intervening sequence between two locations:

http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/das/hg19/dna?segment=chr1:100,200